# systemd failed at step user spawning no such process

Tags: linux, systemctl

I am trying to run my custom service using systemctl, but it alwasy gave me error:

```
Oct 29 14:09:30 ip-10-0-0-215.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[12402]: Failed at step USER spawning /home/ec2-user/zuul/target/zuul.jar: No such process
Oct 29 14:09:30 ip-10-0-0-215.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: zuul.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Oct 29 14:09:30 ip-10-0-0-215.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit zuul.service entered failed state.
Oct 29 14:09:30 ip-10-0-0-215.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: zuul.service failed.
```

the configuration in zuul.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=leave service
[Service]
User=ec2-user
# The configuration file application.properties should be here:
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user
#path to executable.
#executable is a bash script which calls jar file
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/project-error-404/microservice/leaveService/target/leaveService.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

how i run the service is:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable zuul.service
sudo systemctl start zuul
```

I have tried remove user from the service file but it does not help.
I am sure that the owner of the file and directory is ec2-user.
And with the same configuration, it can run on my other instances.
But i have spent hours on this and i had no solution.

Comment: Any chance that user would be somehow disabled? Or non-existent (if non-default AMI?). Similar error reported a while ago: https://superuser.com/questions/1156676/what-causes-systemd-failed-at-step-user-spawning-usr-sbin-opendkim-no-such-p

Comment: i am sure that user exists, but how can i check whether user is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I think i find out why. i need to install java run time. BUT the error log is not helpful at all, i just randomly tried everything possible to fix this.

the weird thing is that i can run it perfectly on a normal command,(but i installd java with sdkman, and i think this is the reason)

so for me solution is just sudo yum install java